# Debmirror for local repo sync. Missing packages?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, mirror

So I've setup a local mirror using Debmirror which works great for Patching but when I type to install software e.g vnstat or multitail it doesn't seem to be available from my mirror.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror

If I pull down the packages using apt-get from an internet connected machine it pulls from ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe

The Debmirror config includes universe and multiverse:

```
# Minimum Ubuntu system requires main, restricted
# Section=      -s      # Section (One of the following - main/restricted/universe/multiverse).
# You can add extra file with $Section/debian-installer. ex: main/debian-installer,universe/debian-installer,multiverse/debian-installer,restricted/debian-installer
#
section=main,restricted,universe,multiverse
```

On a host using my local mirror repo I get

> E: Unable to locate package vnstat

Answer (score -1):

So I figured out I was missing bits in the `sources.list` on the machines that were trying to use the local mirror.

I didn't have the entries for universe and multiverse

```
deb http://${mirrorbox-hostname}/ubuntu focal main restricted **universe** **multiverse**

deb http://${mirrorbox-hostname}/ubuntu focal-security main restricted **universe** **multiverse**

deb http://${mirrorbox-hostname}/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted **universe** **multiverse**
```

Basic mistake.